# My computer keeps turning itself off but things appear to update when it turns on

Tags: package-management, upgrade, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux, helpfile

dbus, dbus-bin, dbus-daemon, dbus-session-bus-common, dbus-system- bus-common, dconf-gsettings-backend, dconf-service, dmsetup, dpkg, gir 1.2-girepository-2.0, gir1.2-glib-2.0, gpgv, gstreamer1.0-plugins-base, krb5-locales, libapparmor 1, libbikid 1, libbrotlit, libcairo2, libcap-ngo, libcom-err2, libdbus-1-3, libdconf 1, libdebconfcliento, libdevmapper1.02.1, libfdiskt, libfreetype6, libgirepository-1.0-1, libglib2.0-bin, libglib2.0-data, libgssapi-krb5-2, libgstreamer-plugins- base1.0-0, libgstreamer1.0-0, libgudev-1.0-0, libjson-glib-1.0-0, libjson- glib-1.0-common, libk5crypto3, libkmod2, libkrb5-3, libkrb5supporto, libldap-common, libldap2, libmount 1, libnghttp2-14, libnmo, libopenjp2-7, libpam-modules, libpam-modules-bin, libpam-runtime, libpamig, libpolkit-agent-1-0, libpolkit-gobject-1-0, libpoppler 134, libpython3-stdlib, libpython3.12-minimal, libpython3.12-stdlib, libseccomp2, libselinuxt, libsharpyuvo, libsmartcolst, libsoup-3.0-0, libsoup-3.0-common, libsqlite3-0, libssh-4, libsystemd-shared, libsystemdo, libtheorat, libtiffs, libtirpc-common, libudev1, libusb-1.0-0, libuurdt, libwebp?, libxml2, mount, openssi, peri-base, polkitd, python3, python-dbus, python-gi, python3-minimal, python3. 12, python3.12- minimal, readline-common, shared-mime info, systemd, systemd-dev, systemd resolved, systemd-timesyncd, udev, uuid-runtime, zlib1g

appears to update all this. how can I do this?
it turns off in the middle of use but it's not the battery, it's possibly something in the system; any opinions?

Comment: Only english, please. Please also provide sufficient context, Ubuntu version for example. If you provide command output, also provide the exact command you ran to produce the output.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

All content on Ask Ubuntu and most other Stack Exchange sites [must be written in English](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)—Please translate your post to English or repost on a language appropriate-SE site.  Thank you!